# using Ajax to parse through live xml feed

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml

i'm trying to make a live transit app showing live bus locations in Laval, QC (Canada). 
They provide their bus locations in this [live bus xml feed](http://webservices.nextbus.com/service/publicXMLFeed?command=vehicleLocations&a=stl), though i'm unsure how to pull each bus's "lat" and "long" attributes from the feed and possibly put them into an array of coordinates, or a JSON file.

Any help would be much appreciated, 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options here, you either parse the feed information server side with something like PHP, Python, Java or whatever other technology you use on the server, or you do it client side with Javascript.

I see you tagged this with Javascript, so I'm going to give you the answer on how to do it with Javascript/JQuery. If you don't know about JQuery, well, it's time you step into it and learn some before digging in here. Anyways here is the way to do it with JS/Jquery.

```
var serviceUrl = http://webservices.nextbus.com/service/publicXMLFeed?command=vehicleLocations&a=stl';

$(document).ready(function(e){
        $.ajax({
            url : serviceUrl,
            method : 'GET',
            dataType : 'xml',
            success : function(data){
                // This one below finds all the vehicle nodes
                // and parse each of them individually.
                $(data).find('vehicle').each(function(index, vehicle){
                    // Get the vehicle lat
                    var lat = $(vehicle).attr('lat');
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Would be goood you can check about the JQuery's .each, .find and $.ajax methods and functions so you can really understand what's going on. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for this! I ended up doing a much messier job with ajax, though seeing as this is much smoother I think i'll use this method (I was storing everything in a global variable, and pushing the attributes into a json object).

Thank you again though! this is my first stackoverflow question :)

Comment: Ok, your welcome. There are probably many things to explain in that chunk of code. You'll find the understanding studying the $.ajax() method in JQuery though. The `var serviceUrl` I set above can be within the `$(document).ready()` below too.